# pipを使いgspreadをインストールしようとするとエラーがでる

Tags: python, google-spreadsheet, pip

PythonとGoogle spread sheetの連携をはかりたいです。

そこでpipを使いgspreadをインストールしようとすると下記のようなエラーがでます。

```
実行コマンド
$ pip install gspread
```

---

```
エラー
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gspread (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for gspread
```

- エラーに対する対処の仕方がわからない
- 連携するにあたりgspreadというライブラリを使うのが普通なのかを知りたい

ご教授いただければ幸いです,よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 下記のようなエラーとはどのようなエラーですか？よろしければエラーのメッセージなど状況がわかるものを張り付けていただけませんか？

Comment: Haru様。失礼いたしました、コードの方追加しておきます。ご指摘いただきありがとうございます。

Comment: どんなコマンドを実行していますか？実行したコマンドをそのまま貼り付けると回答がつきやすいと思います。

Comment: tell k様。ご指摘ありがとうございます,実行コマンドの方追加いたしました。

Comment: gspread以外のインストールは正常に動作しますか？お使いの環境ではProxyが必用ですか？

Comment: take88様。コメントいただきありがとうございます。他のインストールは正常通り動作いたします。恥ずかしながらProxyのことは詳しく理解していなかったので、これを機に勉強させていただきます。自分の希望としましては、Pythonとなにかしらの表を連携させたいと考えております次第です。

Comment: `pip --version` の結果と、OS の情報を追記して頂けませんか？

Comment: pip                       9.0.1            py36hbd95645_3  
pip                       9.0.3                     <pip>  　　と表示されました。OSのバージョンはMac OS　10.13.3　になります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

すいません。Windowsではないんですよね。
この辺はLinuxとかでも変わらないんでしょうか。
一応後で編集の可能性があるということで載せておきますね。
（↓以前の投稿）

`pip`でインストールできれば楽なのですが、正常に動作しない場合がありますね。
[gspread 2.1.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gspread)
ここから、例えば、.whlファイルをダウンロードします。
よくよく見れば、２０１８年４月６日に更新され、アップロードされています。
昨日じゃありませんか。

**.whlファイルを取り込むには。**
1.コマンドプロンプトを開きます。
2.先ほどダウンロードしたwhlファイルがある場所へ行きます。わかりにくい場所にある場合は、whlファイルの方を、たどり着きやすい場所へ移してください。
（注：私の場合、whlファイルを右クリックすると、このファイルは他のコンピューターから取得したものです。という、セキュリティの制限がかかっていましたので、外さなければ手続きを進める事が出来ないかもしれません。もう一度試してみたら、外さなくてもいけました。）

```
pip install gspread-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

と、コマンドへ入力。

私の環境は、`Anaconda`の、`python3.6.3`用なので、`Anaconda Prompt`から行きました。
通常の`Command Prompt`でも、`Python`が使えるならいけるのではないでしょうか。ちなみにこの方法ではなく、最初から、`pip install gspread`としたら、私もエラーが出ました。

うまくいけば幸いですが、`pip`それ自体でどうして解決できないのかという質問に直接お答えできているわけではありません。
　
　参照
　[Qiita pipとwheelをWindowsでも使いこなす](https://qiita.com/toruuetani/items/b0000e9f5c89a350d4f8)

この中には、`pip`はバイナリをインストールすることが出来ないと言われています。このことから推察すると、`pip`独自の能力の限界にあるのではないでしょうか。それを、`whl`ファイルなどで拡張しているということでしょうね。

Comment: Haru様、ご回答ありがとうございます。Anaconda Promptから無事行けることができました。誠にありがとうございました。深く感謝いたします。